# How to lookup and match in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, match, lookup

I have 2 collections like:

collectionA:
{
_id: "id1",
...props.
}

collectionB:
{
_id: "id2",
collectionA_id: "id1",
property_x: 3,
...props.
}

When I will join with lookup how can I also filter by collectionB.property_x?

So Im trying like:

```
{
"$lookup": {
"from" => "",
'localField' => '_id',
'foreignField' => 'job_id',
'as' => 'collB'
},
"$match": {
"collB.property_x": 3
}
}
```

How is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. Imagine you have two collections like this:

```
db.collectionA.insert({_id: 1, field: "hey"});
db.collectionA.insert({_id: 2, field: "hey2"});
db.collectionA.insert({_id: 3, field: "hey3"});

db.collectionB.insert({_id:1, fk: 1, cnt: 4});
db.collectionB.insert({_id:2, fk: 2, cnt: 0});
```

Let's say that fk field represents some kind of "foreign key" relationship. We want to use **$lookup** to embed documents from collectionB into collectionA. Lookup is quite flexible so it embeds dependant documents as an array since there can be one to many relationship. What we have to do is to **$unwind** this nested array to have only one embedded item from collectionB in each document and then we can execute **$match** on such entries. So my entire query looks like this:

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "collectionB",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "fk",
      as: "relation"
    }
  },
  {
     $unwind: "$relation"
  },
  {
     $match: {"relation.cnt": 0}
  }
 ]);
```